# Create a custom scroll event, distinguishable from user event?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how can I dispatch a synthetic event that will be picked up by `onscroll`, where the event holds some flag telling me that it's a synthetic event, and doesn't originate from the user

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom event with the `Event` constructor as follows:

```
var event = new Event('build');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { ... }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

To add more data to the event object, the `CustomEvent` interface exists and the detail property can be used to pass custom data.
For example, the event could be created as follows:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('build', { 'detail': elem.dataset.time });
```

This will then allow you to access the additional data in the event listener:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
  console.log('The time is: ' + e.detail);
}
```

[details are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CustomEvent()` constructor, `.dispatchEvent()`, check if `"detail"` property is `in` `event`; if `true` and

```
element.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {     
  if ("detail" in event && event.detail.id === 123) {
    // do stuff with `event.detail.prop`
  }
});

var id = 123;
var o = {detail:{id: id, prop:"abc"}};

var e = new CustomEvent("scroll", o);
element.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `event["detail"] && event["detail"]`

Comment: @KScandrett Yes, see updated post. Alternatively, `if ("detail" in event){}`